# Mysql on Ubuntu - variables - syntax error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have mysql 8 installed on Ubuntu and when I do:

```
SET @test := 'test'; SELECT @test;
```

Then I have error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'SELECT @test' at line 1

Why? Should I set something special in mysql configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use multi-query, sending more than one SQL statement in a single call to the query interface. This is not supported in most client connectors by default. Some connectors have an option to enable it.

Multi-query is not supported for prepared statements regardless of any connector options.

The use cases for multi-query are very rare exceptions. Almost certainly you don't need to use multi-query.

Instead, submit one SQL statement per call to the query interface. Your session variable `@test` will retain its value on subsequent calls using the same MySQL session.

Comment: Then how can I set variables before select?

Comment: Use two separate calls to the query interface, one to execute the `SET` statement, and a second call to execute the `SELECT` statement using the same MySQL session.